# Fade out/in animation of ImageView in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to experiment with gradually fading-out the image (so that it becomes invisible) and then immediately reversing that so it gradually becomes visible again.

I have a simple Xamarin Android app with a solid black background, an `ImageView` displaying an image, and a `Button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="400px"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/clownfish"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In `OnCreate()` I set the image to fully opaque and set a click handler for the button:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        this.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView).Alpha = 1.0f;
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn).Click += Btn_Click;
    }
```

In the click handler I create a pair of animations each with a duration of 5 seconds, set the second animation to start after 5 seconds, add them to an `AnimationSet`, and animate the animation set on the `ImageView`:

```
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const long duration = 5000L;
        var imgView = this.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);

        var fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f)  // fully opaque -> fully transparent
        {
            Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator(),
            Duration = duration
        };
        var fadeIn =  new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f)  // fully transparent -> fully opaque
        {
            Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator(),
            Duration = duration 
        };

        fadeIn.StartOffset = duration;
        var animSet = new AnimationSet(false);
        animSet.AddAnimation(fadeOut);
        animSet.AddAnimation(fadeIn);
        imgView.StartAnimation(animSet);
    }
```

When I click the button the `ImageView` **immediately** becomes transparent, and after 10 seconds it becomes immediately fully opaque again. There is no gradual transition from opaque to transparent and back to opaque. I don't understand why this doesn't do what I want.

If I replace the `AnimationSet` code in the click handler with:

```
        fadeOut.AnimationEnd += (s, e) => { imgView.StartAnimation(fadeIn); };
        imgView.StartAnimation(fadeOut);
```

then the animation works correctly. I'm happy with the working code, particularly as it is briefer, and I understand what it does - but I don't understand why the approach that uses an `AnimationSet` doesn't perform a smooth animation. As this is a learning exercise, can anyone explain to me why the first approach doesn't work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I created a demo and achieved this function.

You can refer to  the following code:

1.set the property `android:visibility="invisible"` for this image.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
    <ImageView
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="400px"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/fish"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

2.function `Btn_Click`

```
    ImageView imgView; 
    AlphaAnimation fadeIn;
    AlphaAnimation fadeOut;


    private void Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        const long duration = 5000L;
        imgView = this.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);


         fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1)  // fully transparent -> fully opaque
        {
            Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator(),  //AccelerateInterpolator
            Duration = duration,
        };

         fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0)  // fully opaque -> fully transparent
        {
            Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator(),
            Duration = duration,

            StartOffset = 3000
        };
        
        AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(false);

        imgView.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
        animSet.AddAnimation(fadeIn);
        animSet.AddAnimation(fadeOut);
        
        imgView.Animation=animSet;
        animSet.StartNow();

  }
```